# Is Red Eye Orb only usable while in Darkwraith covenant?

Tags: dark-souls

Is [Red Eye Orb](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/red-eye-orb) only usable while in Darkwraith covenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh....your answer is in the link you posted:

> Note that you can no longer use it if you leave the Darkwraiths